# RSS Widget For iOS 14 Shows Empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widget

I use an XMLParser for my app written in Swift, and am trying to get a Widget set up for iOS 14 in which it will show the most recent article on the RSS. I see the placeholder just fine when I add it, but it stays empty with just a line where text should be and never seems to get the information from the timeline.

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    @State private var rssItems:[RSSItem]?
    let feedParser = FeedParser()
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), title:"News", description: "News article here", link: "Http://link", pubDate: "The day it posted")
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), title:"News", description: "News Article Here", link: "Http://link", pubDate: "The day it posted")
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        feedParser.parseFeed(url: "http://fritchcoc.wordpress.com/feed") {(rssItems) in
            self.rssItems = rssItems
            let currentDate = Date()
                let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, title:rssItems[0].title, description: rssItems[0].description, link: rssItems[0].link, pubDate: rssItems[0].pubDate)
                entries.append(entry)
            
        
      
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let link: String
    let pubDate: String
}

struct FritchNewsEntryView : View {
    var entry: SimpleEntry
    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                
                Text(entry.title)
               
                   
                
              
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.orange, .yellow]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        }
    
}

@main
struct FritchNews: Widget {
    let kind: String = "FritchNews"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            FritchNewsEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE BY THE OP:
It was indeed a combination of the timeline being set in the wrong spot, along with a couple of typos within the parser that caused this particular issue.

Apple does not allow HTTP connections by default, the easiest solution is to change the URL to `https://fritchcoc.wordpress.com/feed`

If you want to allow HTTP connections in your app (or widget) you can add exceptions (to one domain or all) in the Info.plist for the target, see NSAppTransportSecurity at [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

**Edit:**
After a better look and finding for the implementation of `FeedParser` online, I noticed that `parseFeed()` is asynchronous.

Thus the completion is called with an empty array, it should be called after the parsing is done:

```swift
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        feedParser.parseFeed(url: "http://fritchcoc.wordpress.com/feed") {(rssItems) in
            self.rssItems = rssItems
            let currentDate = Date()
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, title:rssItems[0].title, description: rssItems[0].description, link: rssItems[0].link, pubDate: rssItems[0].pubDate)
            entries.append(entry)
            
        
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything...I had already set the exception for NSAppTransportSecurity

Comment: Seems like feedParser.parseFeed is asynchronous, thus the completion is called before entries has a anything inside.

Move:
```swift
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
completion(timeline)
```
to the end of `parseFeed` block so the completion is called after the pase is finished

Comment: I can’t get it to print to console to make sure it isn’t returning null when parsing

Comment: Try to clean the build folder (Cmd+Shift+K) and run it again, also make sure you are running the Widget target and not the app. It is working for me with my change, but I cannot be sure I am using the same code as you since I found FeedParser online

Comment: Will try that after I get some charge on battery and coffee in my system. Shouldn’t simulator be able to work if running the app and adding a widget to Home Screen? The parser I used was from this tutorial https://www.ductran.co/45

Comment: It works, but you wont see the logs if you are debugging the App, they are different processes

Comment: I mean it gives me error messages in Xcode trying to do a print on anything in the widget code

Comment: Mm, I am not sure of what could case that. Xcode sometimes can be unstable, but usually fixes itself after a restart or Clean Build folder

Comment: I put `print("WORKDANGIT")` in the XMLParser object I set up, and it never shows in the Xcode Console, so I don't think it's ever even trying to run the parser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221948/discussion-between-itay-brenner-and-user717452).

Comment: So, I did the whole .after deal for refreshing, and for whatever reason, it is actually 50 minutes before it refreshes, even though I set value to 2 minutes. I printed the date and confirmed it to be 2 minutes after opening the app, but it still doesn't work right.